# Efficiently finding arrays with the most occurences of the same number

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

Let's say I have the following nested array:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 7, 9, 13],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3]
    [12, 15, 16]
]
```

I only need the arrays with the most occurrences of the same numbers. In the above example this would be:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 7, 9, 13],
    [12, 15, 16]
]
```

How can I do this efficiently with C#?

**EDIT**
Indeed my question is really confusing. What I wanted to ask is: How can I eliminate sub-arrays if some bigger sub-array already contains all the elements of a smaller sub-array.

My current implementation of the problem is the following:

```
var allItems = new List<List<int>>{
            new List<int>{1, 2, 3},
            new List<int>{4, 7, 9, 13},
            new List<int>{1, 2},
            new List<int>{2, 3},
            new List<int>{12, 15, 16}
        };

var itemsToEliminate = new List<List<int>>();

for(var i = 0; i < allItems.ToList().Count; i++){
    var current = allItems[i];
    var itemsToVerify = allItems.Where(item => item != current).ToList();
    foreach(var item in itemsToVerify){
        bool containsSameNumbers = item.Intersect(current).Any();
        if(containsSameNumbers && item.Count > current.Count){
            itemsToEliminate.Add(current);          
        }
    }
}
allItems.RemoveAll(item => itemsToEliminate.Contains(item));
foreach(var item in allItems){
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item));
}
```

This does work, but the nested loops `for(var i = 0; i < allItems.ToList().Count; i++)` and `foreach(var item in itemsToVerify)` gives it a bad performance. Especially if you know that the `allItems` array can contain about 10000000 rows.

Comment: What do you mean, "most occurrences of the same numbers"? All of the items in your example result only have one occurrence of each number, and have no numbers in common...

Comment: What is the most occurences of the same number? Not only do all your arrays contain each number they hold only once, but your result arrays don't share any numbers between them. if it were all the arrays with the number 2 in them (2 occurs 3 times total, which is more than all the other numbers.), I would've gotten it, but this is just confusing.

Comment: @FalcoGer, I think TS means that he needs to eliminate sub-arrays if some bigger sub-array already contains all the elements of a smaller sub-array

Comment: @JuryGolubev i think if he means that he should very well say that. I don't want to guess an answer.  
Even so, what is the desired behavior of an array contains both numbers that occured before and not. should the array be included? Should it be included if a later array adds the same numbers with less previously occuring numbers?  
Also what's the end goal here? Is this homework? Certainly seems like it.

Comment: What you are doing is eliminating [1,2] because it is contained in [1, 2, 3].  The only way of doing this is to check each object to see if it is in any of the other objects.   I think a sort may speed up results.  I would order arrays from longest to shortest.  Then starting at shortest to see if it is in the longest, then next longest, and so on.  If shortest is in longest then remove and go to next shortest until each array is compared against all others.

Comment: @jdweng I would call that an assumption.

Comment: @FalcoGer It matches the results posted.  What you want to so is to spend three days asking (playing 50 questions) what the op wants because he doesn't know how to describe the algorithm.  I'm giving the results in one answer.

Comment: @FalcoGer I agree, that why I edited the question.

Comment: @user2810895 retracted the downvote. in any case, what is to happen if a list has items from different lists? say instead of `new List<int>{2, 3}` it was `new List<int>{2, 4}`?

Comment: That unexpected behavior. You can see the `int`s as an id of a person. Each group of `int`s forms, for example, a family. If the algorithm creates `[2, 4]`, then we are creating, for example, an extramarital relationship. Which is not desirable.

Answer (score 2):

I would remember the items that are already in the list.
First sort your lists by decreasing length, then check for each item if it's already present.
Given your algorithm, the array is not added if even a single integer is in the list already of known integers already.

Therefore I would use the following algorithm:

```
List<List<int>> allItems = new List<List<int>>{
    new List<int>{1, 2, 3},
    new List<int>{4, 7, 9, 13},
    new List<int>{1, 2},
    new List<int>{2, 3},
    new List<int>{12, 15, 16}
};

allItems = allItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ToList(); // order by length, decreasing order

List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
SortedSet<int> knownItems = new SortedSet<int>(); // keep track of numbers, so you don't have to loop arrays
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

foreach (List<int> l in allItems)
{
    // bool allUnique = true;
    foreach (int elem in l)
    {
        if (knownItems.Contains(elem))
        {
            // allUnique = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // OK, because duplicates not allowed in single list
            // and because how the data is constrained (I still have my doubts about how the data is allowed to look and what special cases may pop up that ruin this, so use with care)
            // this WILL cause problems if a list starts with any number which has not yet been provided appears before the first match that would cause the list to be discarded.
            knownItems.Add(elem);
        }
    }
    // see comment above near knownItems.Add()
    /*
    if (allUnique)
    {
        result.Add(l);
        foreach (int elem in l)
        {
            knownItems.Add(elem);
        }
    }
    */
}

// output
foreach(List<int> item in result){
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item));
}
```

Instead of looping over your original array twice nestedly (O(n^2)), you only do it once (O(n)) and do a search in known numbers (binary search tree lookup: O(n*log2(n))).
Instead of removing from the array, you add to a new one. This uses more memory for the new array. The reordering is done because it is more likely that any subsequent array contains numbers already processed. However sorting a large amount of lists may be slower than the benefit you gain if you have many small lists. If you have even a few long ones, this may pay off.

Sorting your list of lists by the length is valid because

> what is to happen if a list has items from different lists? say instead of new List{2, 3} it was new List{2, 4}?

> That unexpected behavior. You can see the ints as an id of a person. Each group of ints forms, for example, a family. If the algorithm creates [2, 4], then we are creating, for example, an extramarital relationship. Which is not desirable.

From this I gather the arrays will contain subsets of at most only one other array or be unique. Therefore the Order is irrelevant.
This also assumes that at least one such array would contain all elements of such subsets (and therefore be the longest one and come first.)
The sorting could be removed if it were not so, and should probably be removed if in doubt.

For example:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} - contains all elements that future arrays will have subsets of
{1, 4, 5} - must contain no element that {1,2,3,4,5} does not contain
{1, 2, 6} - illegal in this case
{7, 8 ,9} - OK
{8, 9} - OK (will be ignored)
{7, 9} - OK (will be ignored, is only subset in {7,8,9})
{1, 7} - - illegal, but would be legal if {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9} was in this list. because it is longer it would've been earlier, making this valid to ignore.
```

Comment: Is there any benefit using `OrderBy(x => -x.Count())` instead of `OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())`? I haven't checked, but I assume these would return the same result.

Comment: @Klicker I guess not. To be honest I didn't think of `OrderByDescending()`.

Comment: I think you can eliminate the `knownItems.Add(elem);` loop. If you add it as an else condition in the `if (knownItems.Contains(elem))` loop

Comment: @user2810895 I suppose that is true given the format of the data. I would definitely test it though.

Comment: I am not 100% sure which special cases may pop up that ruin this solution. please do test it thoroughly.